# How can I remove the Class Label from the detected object using TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I am trying to remove the label appearing above the detected object box (in my case: Human_hand: 96%). Do you have any idea? Here is how it looks like:

[image]

I am using the following code to display the detected boxes inside the image, how can I edit it to be able to hide the label?

```
while(True):

    # Acquire frame and expand frame dimensions to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
    # i.e. a single-column array, where each item in the column has the pixel RGB value
    ret, frame = video.read()
    frame_expanded = np.expand_dims(frame, axis=0)

    # Perform the actual detection by running the model with the image as input
    (boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run(
        [detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],
        feed_dict={image_tensor: frame_expanded})

    # Draw the results of the detection (aka 'visulaize the results')
    vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
        frame,
        np.squeeze(boxes),
        np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
        np.squeeze(scores),
        category_index,
        use_normalized_coordinates=True,
        line_thickness=8,
        min_score_thresh=0.60)

    # All the results have been drawn on the frame, so it's time to display it.
    cv2.imshow('Object detector', frame)

    # Press 'q' to quit
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

# Clean up
video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Logic is written in this function visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array. Check its definition.

Comment: Yes, I just found the another hidden parameters!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass `skip_labels=True` in `vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array`